Does Dowker's theorem actually hold on bipartite graphs?
Background: Dowker's theorem
Let $X, Y$ be two totally ordered sets, and let $R \subseteq X \times Y$ be a nonempty relation. Then one defines two simplicial complexes $K_X$ and $K_Y$ as follows. A finite subset $\sigma \subseteq X$ belongs to $K_X$ whenever there exists $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ for each $x \in \sigma$. Similarly a finite subset $\tau \subseteq Y$ belongs to $K_Y$ whenever there exists $x \in X$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ for each $y \in \tau$. Then for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, we have $H_k(K_X) \cong H_k(K_Y)$. That is to say the homology of two simplicial complexes are isomorphic.
Problem: Application on bipartite graph
Given a bipartite graph $G(X, Y, E)$, two Dowker complexes can be naturally constructed. For example, below is a bipartite graph.

And we can transform it into two Dowker complexes.

But I don't think these two complexes are isomorphic, and apparently their persistence
diagrams are not the same. Why is this happening? Do I understand wrongly?

Can you post your homology calculations?

Also you're missing an edge in the left side complex.

@SteveD To be honest, I am not a student majoring in mathematics. In my own understanding, simply, $K_x$ has a loop while $K_y$ has not.

@SteveD Which missing edge?

1-3, no? From the yellow node 2.

@SteveD Because [0, 1, 3, 4] is a 3-simplex, and [1, 3] is a face of it. So I don't draw it on the figure.

These simplicial complexes are both contractible, so they do have the same homology (in particular, since the "loop" you see in $K_x$ is filled in it doesn't yield a nontrivial element of $H_1$).

These simplicial complexes are both contractible, so they do have the same homology groups. In particular, since the "loop" you see in $K_x$ is filled in it doesn't yield a nontrivial element of $H_1$. Homology is often a coarser invariant than one may expect.
Given that homology is also a bit abstract, it may be easier to convince yourself first that these two complexes have isomorphic fundamental groups, i.e. $\pi_1(K_X)\cong\pi_1(K_Y)$. Again, the key point is contractibility.

Thanks for your answer. I have another question about persistent homology. Are the persistent diagrams of these two Dowker complexes the same?

@LizhiLiu I'm not familiar with persistent homology, so I can't answer that. But my vague recollection is that the diagram is actually quite sensitive to how the complex is "presented" so to speak, so in this case I wouldn't expect them to be.

I tried to use Gudhi library to compute the persistent homology of two complexes. The persistence diagram is related to the setting of filtrations. So I found the diagrams are not the same. Thank you for answer!
